# Is a placebo test the proper solution to this type of research issue?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, causality, difference-in-difference

I'd like to study the effect of the immigration quota on immigration petitions. I predict that in anticipation of the greater difficulty of being approved, potential immigrants will be less likely to petition. However, the quota itself also limit the number of petitions approved. How can I disentangle the direct effect (reduced number of petitions approved as a result of the quota itself) from the indirect effect that fewer petitions are submitted. I can only observe the decrease in the number of approved petitions. I used a difference-in-difference method to remove the trend effect. But a placebo test is suggested. Any idea if this is appropriate? If so, what would be a good placebo test? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. How many units and time periods do you have?

Comment: Thank you! About 7,000 observations and 24 time periods.

Comment: Is it 7,000 individuals or geographic units? I assume the immigration quota impacts countries/regions. I’m curious to know if you’re working with panel data or repeated cross-sections.